# Realm: please show how to properly create objects

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

I have RealmData.swift with two classes:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Task : Object {
    dynamic var taskName = ""
    dynamic var taskStatus = ""
}

class TaskList : Object {
    dynamic var listName = ""
    let tasks = List<Task>()
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement demo fill in for Realm to show it later in my UITableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ListsTableViewController: UITableViewController, ListCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
// (...)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // (...)
    let list_0 = TaskList(value: ["Things for vaction", [["Cash & Cards", false], ["Clothes", false], ["Passport", false] ] ])
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.write {
        realm.add(list_0)
    }
}
}
```

This code should by design create a List with name "Things for vacation" having 3 tasks with names "Cash & Cards", "Clothes" and "Passport" and false taskStatus'es.
When I add "let list_0 = (...)" line and run, app crashes on start with "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" exception. Am I misspelling something or may be it's required to create Task objects first? But https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ has the same example:

```
let aPerson = Person(value: ["Jane", 30, [["Buster", 5], ["Buddy", 6]]])
```

Explain please, what is wrong with this?
I'm fine with Current Limitations (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#current-limitations)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't match the type of the property.

You pass array object for `Task` as `["Cash & Cards", false]`. The array contains `String` and `Bool` value. Otherwise, your model definition of `Task` has only `String` properties. So the latter value doesn't match, pass the `boolean` value but model expects `String` value.

So the solution is: make your model containing `String` and `Bool` properties. Like below

```
class Task : Object {
    dynamic var taskName = ""
    dynamic var taskStatus = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see, my question was really stupid :D

Comment: But it still fails on `let realm = try! Realm()` yet with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode 0x0)`

Comment: Hmm, It's odd. Please make sure what error happened? Rewrite your code to `do  { let realm = try Realm() } catch let error { print(error) }` to see the error.

Comment: `do { let realm = try Realm() ; realm.write { realm.add(list_0) } } catch let error { print(error) }` runs with no errors at all. Yes, it's really odd. Double checked: `let realm = try! Realm()` fails, your suggested do{} catch{} runs smoothly.

Comment: Really strange. Is the data actually written to disk? And if your code to change to  `let realm = try? Realm()` `print(realm)`, what does it show in the console?

Comment: It returns nil. So it fails on further realm!.write than.

Comment: Oh it now throws `fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Migration is required for object type 'Task' due to the following errors:
- Property types for 'taskStatus' property do not match. Old type 'string', new type 'bool'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required for object type 'Task' due to the following errors:`
(to be continued)

Comment: `- Property types for 'taskStatus' property do not match. Old type 'string', new type 'bool'}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 50
(lldb) ` with let realm= try! Realm() . May be I should find existing realm file and get rid of it.

Comment: Yes. Remove the app then re-try!

Comment: Finally! Thank you for help!